# How to calculate this sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^k} \binom nk$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

How do you calculate this sum

$$ \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^k}{n\choose k} \;?$$

Comment: Set $x = \frac{1}{n}$ after calculating $$\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^k = x \sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{k-1}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $n-k = (n-1) - (k-1)$,
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^k}\binom{n}{k}
= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n^{k-1}}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}
= \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}
$$
now do a change of variable to get, by the binomial expansion,
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^k}\binom{n}{k}
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k \binom{n-1}{k}
= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}
$$

Comment: Can you please explain last equality sign. I can see the transition.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over n^{k}}{n\choose k}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over n^{k}}{n\choose k}}&=
> \left. x\,\partiald{}{x}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{n\choose k}x^{k}\right\vert_{x\ =\ 1/n}
> =\left. x\,\partiald{\pars{1 + x}^{n}}{x}\right\vert_{x\ =\ 1/n}
> =\left. \vphantom{\huge A}x\,n\pars{1 + x}^{n - 1}\right\vert_{x\ =\ 1/n}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#f00}{1 \over n}\,n\pars{1 + \color{#f00}{1 \over n}}^{n - 1}
> =\color{#00f}{\large\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}^{n - 1}}
> \end{align}